# AngularJS: ng-click not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, click

I have a group-button with is included in a template `add-new-document-template.html`:

```
<div class="col-sm-4" style="text-align: right">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{active: layout == 'list'}"
                    ng-click="listView()">
                <i class="fa fa-list-ul fa-lg"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{active: layout == 'grid'}" ng-click="gridView()">
                <i class="fa fa-th fa-lg"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the directive: it's inculeded in an a parent directive

```
angular.module('bdocinteractive.addNewDocument')
.constant("NEW_DOC_TEMP_URL", {
    url: 'src/app/add-new-document/add-new-document-template.html'
})
.directive("addNewDocument", ["NEW_DOC_TEMP_URL", function (tempURL) {
    return {
        scope: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: 'AddNewDocumentController',
        controllerAs: "addDocCtrl",
        templateUrl: tempURL.url
    }
}]);
```

And here is my Controller:

```
angular.module("bdocinteractive.addNewDocument").
controller("AddNewDocumentController", ["$scope", "AddNewDocumentService",
    function ($scope, AddNewDocumentService) {
        var me = this;
        $scope.gridView = function () {
            $scope.layout = "grid";
        };
        $scope.listView = function () {
            $scope.layout = "list";
        };
        $scope.models = [];
        $scope.layout = "list";
        $scope.modelSelectedId = "";
        AddNewDocumentService.getAllModels().success(function (data) {
            $scope.models = data;
        });
    }]
);
```

When clicking on the button, the ng-click is not fired

Can you help me please

NB: I'am working with Angular 1.3.15 Version

Comment: what is `alert` defined as ? if you are hoping to use the javascript `alert` it wont work.. you need to create a function within the scope which will use `alert` within it..

Comment: `ng-click` can only contain calls to functions defined in the `$scope`, while `alert` belongs to `window`, and cannot be used directly.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/hLqUG4POxhq8mL7CRxcd?p=preview

Comment: At the first time I created a method in my controller and I called It from my template, but I had the same problem, so I tried with `alert` the javascript method

Comment: I will edit it with the origin problem

Answer (score 4):

Do you have an `alert` method defined on your `$scope`? Expressions in `ng-click` are not evaled on the global object (window), so you can't reference any global variables in that expression. You need something like:

```
$scope.alert = window.alert;
```

Comment: I added  the controller to my post, I had method related to the `$scope`

Answer (score 0):

This is an  [updated](http://jsbin.com/cevisobika/4/edit) 
answer...

I assume you are having a problem with toggling the value of `$scope.layout` the above example seems to be working.

Comment: But it doesn't work for Me, Your example, is the same as what I posted

Comment: Mine is slightly different i.e i have declared the ng-controller which isn't actually mentioned in yours... sorry i can't be more help

Comment: You're right, i have a directive which isn't mentioned in my Post

Comment: Is that html inside url: 'src/app/add-new-document/add-new-document-template.html'?

Comment: YES it's inside the template for the directive

Comment: I just can't get it to not work haha... [update](http://jsbin.com/cevisobika/4/edit)